# Как сделать одну саб библиотеку зависимой от основной?

Tags: android, c++, cmake

У меня есть нативный андроид проект `CMakeList.txt` все работает. Но теперь мне понадобилось добавить еще нативного кода и нужно это сделать отдельным модулем. Для этого я создаю `Android lib` (lib_tet_decoder) `File->New->NewModule->AndroidLib`, этот модуль имеет свой `CMakeList.txt` который знает как его собрать. Что получается, у меня есть основной нативный модуль который уже работает и теперь мне нужно подключить саб нативный модуль. Для этого мне нужно сконфигурировать основной `CMakeList.txt` файл , чтоб он знал что у него есть саб модуль и его код нужно использовать.

Согласно вот этому

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#include-other-cmake-projects

я добавляю конфиг в свой смейк

```
...
# Sets libtetdecoder_src_DIR to the path of the target CMake project.
set(LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR ../libtetdecoder)

# Sets lib_build_DIR to the path of the desired output directory.
set(LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR ../libtetdecoder/outputs)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR})

# Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory
# as a build dependency.
add_subdirectory( # Specifies the directory of the CMakeLists.txt file.
        ${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR}

        # Specifies the directory for the build outputs.
        ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR})

# Adds the output of the additional CMake build as a prebuilt static
# library and names it lib_gmath.
add_library(lib_tet_decoder STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_tet_decoder PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/liblibtetdecoder.a)
include_directories(${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        ...
        lib_tet_decoder
        ...)
...
```

Вроде все должно получиться, но когда запускаю получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\co\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe 
with arguments 
{-C C:\TV_repo\co_android\ar_c\libtetplayer\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a libtetcodec libtetdecoder libtetplayer}
ninja: Entering directory `C:\TV_repo\co_android\ar_c\libtetplayer\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a'

ninja: error: '../libtetdecoder/outputs/arm64-v8a/liblibtetdecoder.a', 
needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/liblibtetplayer.so', 
missing and no known rule to make it
```

Как будто он пробует получить .so liblibtetplayer раньше чем он построен. Насколько я понимаю, после того как я указал, что liblibtetplayer это саб модуль он должен его построить, собрать .so liblibtetplayer и только потом пробовать его включить в основную сборку, но что то идет не по плану.

Что делаю не так?

**Правка**

основной CMakeList.txt

```
#A few tips about how to build CMakefile
#https://medium.com/@sourav.bh/build-a-native-android-library-or-module-using-ndk-and-cmake-71988b00b5dd

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


# Sets libtetdecoder_src_DIR to the path of the target CMake project.
set(LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR ../libtetdecoder)

# Sets lib_build_DIR to the path of the desired output directory.
set(LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR ../libtetdecoder/outputs)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR})

# Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory
# as a build dependency.
add_subdirectory( # Specifies the directory of the CMakeLists.txt file.
        ${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR}

        # Specifies the directory for the build outputs.
        ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR})

# Adds the output of the additional CMake build as a prebuilt static
# library and names it lib_gmath.
add_library(lib_tet_decoder STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_tet_decoder PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/liblibtetdecoder.a)
include_directories(${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR}/include)


# Import the ARCore library.
add_library(arcore SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(arcore PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${ARCORE_LIBPATH}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libarcore_sdk_c.so
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ARCORE_INCLUDE}
        )

# Import the glm header file from the NDK.
add_library(glm INTERFACE)
set_target_properties(glm PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/libs/glm)

set(libplayersource
        src/main/cpp/utils/util.cc
        src/main/cpp/jni_interface.cc
        src/main/cpp/co_application.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/background_renderer.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/plane_renderer.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/point_cloud_renderer.cc
        src/main/cpp/opengl_render_manager/opengl_render_mng.cc
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libtetplayer

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libplayersource})

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_include_directories(libtetplayer PRIVATE src/main/cpp)

target_compile_options(libtetplayer PRIVATE
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")

#target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
#        libtetcodec
#        android
#        ${log-lib})

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libtetplayer
        lib_tet_decoder
        arcore
        glm
        GLESv2
        android
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

саб CMakeList.txt

```
#For add OpenCV take a look at this video
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jN9Bv5LHXMk
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fdIiOqCz3o
#Watch these videos than compare with this file and make the same

#!!IMPORTANT!! IF YOU HAVE BUILD ISSUES (LIKE cmake:missing and don't known rule to make it)
#CHECK pathToOpenCv BELLOW AND ALSO CHECK README.txt
#I wrote there some tips
#Version of OpenCV lib is opencv-3.3.1-android-sdk.zip

#A few tips about how to build CMakefile
#https://medium.com/@sourav.bh/build-a-native-android-library-or-module-using-ndk-and-cmake-71988b00b5dd

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(pathToOpenCv $ENV{OPEN_CV_PATH})
set(CMAKE VERBOSE MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE CXX FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(OBOE_DIR ../../oboe)

# Set the path to the parserTet library directory
set(PARSER_TET_DIR ../../../co_main/TV_Infrastructure/Tier1.0/TV_TetFileCodec)
set(PARSER_GWS_DIR ../../../co_main/TV_Infrastructure/Tier1.0/GWStdLib)

include_directories(${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

# Add the Oboe library as a subproject. Since Oboe is an out-of-tree source library we must also
# specify a binary directory
add_subdirectory(${OBOE_DIR} ./oboe-bin)

# Include the Oboe headers and shared sample code
include_directories(${OBOE_DIR}/include ${OBOE_DIR}/samples/shared)

set(libdecodersource
        src/main/cpp/test_class.cpp
        src/main/cpp/jni_interface_tet_decoder.cpp
        src/main/cpp/native_codec/texture_codec.cc
        src/main/cpp/utils/util.cc
        src/main/cpp/utils/configuration.cc
        src/main/cpp/utils/measurer.cc
        src/main/cpp/utils/profiling.cc
        src/main/cpp/utils/loopers/upload_looper.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/model/mtr_frame_manager.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/model/tet_frame_manager.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/utils/condition_event.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/utils/geometry_loader.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/utils/model_render_factory.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/default_dummy_render.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/mtr_render.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/model_render/tet_stream_render.cc
        src/main/cpp/sound/oboe_engine.cc
        src/main/cpp/sound/audio/aasset_data_source.cc
        src/main/cpp/sound/audio/NDK_extractor.cc
        src/main/cpp/sound/audio/player.cc
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libtetdecoder

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libdecodersource})

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

target_include_directories(libtetdecoder PRIVATE src/main/cpp)

# libtetcodec
set(tet_codec_source
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_MtrDecoder.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_TetDecoder.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_TetDecoderImpl.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetDecoder/TV_TetChunkBuffers.cpp
        ${PARSER_TET_DIR}/TV_TetShared/TV_TetTexture.cpp
        ${PARSER_GWS_DIR}/GWS_Basics.cpp)

add_library(libtetcodec SHARED ${tet_codec_source})

# Include parserTet headers
include_directories(${PARSER_TET_DIR})
include_directories(${PARSER_GWS_DIR})

target_compile_options(libtetdecoder PRIVATE
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")

target_compile_options(libtetcodec PRIVATE
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")

target_compile_definitions(libtetcodec PRIVATE IS_LIB_TET_CODEC_DEBUG_MODE=false)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libtetdecoder
        libtetcodec
        oboe
        lib_opencv
        mediandk
        android
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
```

**ПРАВКА2**

```
#A few tips about how to build CMakefile
#https://medium.com/@sourav.bh/build-a-native-android-library-or-module-using-ndk-and-cmake-71988b00b5dd

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


# Sets libtetdecoder_src_DIR to the path of the target CMake project.
set(LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR ../libtetdecoder)

# Sets lib_build_DIR to the path of the desired output directory.
set(LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR ../libtetdecoder/outputs)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR})

# Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory
# as a build dependency.
add_subdirectory( # Specifies the directory of the CMakeLists.txt file.
        ${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR}

        # Specifies the directory for the build outputs.
        ${LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR})



# Import the ARCore library.
add_library(arcore SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(arcore PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${ARCORE_LIBPATH}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libarcore_sdk_c.so
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ARCORE_INCLUDE}
        )

# Import the glm header file from the NDK.
add_library(glm INTERFACE)
set_target_properties(glm PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/libs/glm)

set(libplayersource
        src/main/cpp/utils/util.cc
        src/main/cpp/jni_interface.cc
        src/main/cpp/tetavi_application.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/background_renderer.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/plane_renderer.cc
        src/main/cpp/renders/point_cloud_renderer.cc
        src/main/cpp/opengl_render_manager/opengl_render_mng.cc
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libtetplayer

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libplayersource})

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_include_directories(libtetplayer PRIVATE src/main/cpp)

target_compile_options(libtetplayer PRIVATE
        "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0>")

#target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
#        libtetcodec
#        android
#        ${log-lib})

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libtetplayer
        libtetdecoder
        arcore
        glm
        GLESv2
        android
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

Comment: Убедитесь, что везде используются исключительно абсолютные пути и не забывайте заключать строки в кавычки.

Comment: что-то я не пойму, ваш субмодуль содержит `CMakeLists.txt` или нет? Если есть, то почему вы не используете имя цели из субмодуля, а вместо этого обращаетесь к библиотеке напрямую? И нет, не должен он собирать его до основной сборки - это не так работает. Если cmake может определить зависимость одной цели от другой - тогда да, но у вас то цели не связаны друг с другом

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch добавил в вопрос правку

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, сабмодуль содержит смейк файл. Только я не совсем понял, что значит `имя цели из сабмодуля` ? Вот эти строчки из основного файла `target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        ...
        lib_tet_decoder
        ...)` вот я указываю имя цели из сабмодуля, нет?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko ну вот зачем вы создаете импортированную цель `lib_tet_decoder`, если у вас в субмодуле уже есть нужная цель `libtetdecoder`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch добавил в вопрос правку2, я так понимаю вот так должно быть

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko что касается именно `libtetdecoder` - что то типа того, только зачем задавать переменную `LIBTETDECODER_BUILD_DIR`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да верно, это не обязательно. В итоге получилось вот так `add_subdirectory(${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR})
include_directories(${LIBTETDECODER_SRC_DIR})`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko проблему это решило?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch скорее да чем нет, из за того, что у меня есть зависимости от инклудов в хедерах, то сейчас не получается скомпилировать

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko чего? ничего не понял...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch получается, что libtetdecoder в своих хедах использует еще всякий сторонний код как opencv и еще там другой и теперь когда я добавляю libtetdecoder в свой основной cmake файл, то ему для того, что собрать все нужно тоже знать пути к хедерам для opencv и остального кода который испльзует libtetdecoder. Я в общем добавил include_directories и вроде заработало. Можете добавить как ответ я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Насколько я понимаю, после того как я указал, что liblibtetplayer это саб модуль он должен его построить, собрать .so liblibtetplayer и только потом пробовать его включить в основную сборку" - НЕТ! То что это субмодуль не означает, что он должен собраться раньше, чем цели из корневого `CMakeLists.txt`. Сдесь дело в зависимостях: если ваша цель из основного `CMakeLists.txt` зависит от цели из субмодуля, тогда да, цель из субмодуля будет собрана до завясещей цели - все просто. Но вот ваша цель из основного `cmake` не зависит от цели из субмодуля, а зависит от `imported` цели, которую вы определили в основном файле. Сделано это была, как я понимаю, из-за незнания того, как использовать цели из субмодулей. А использовать их элементарно: просто в `target_link_libraries` указываете имя цели из субмодуля - считайте что эти имена являются глобальными.